# display any number of months with datepicker in rows and columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to show 13 months using multidatespicker. I've get this with below code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('#my_calendar').multiDatesPicker({
            numberOfMonths: [4, 4],
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            defaultDate: '01-01-2015',                
            monthNames: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
            dayNamesMin: ['Lun', 'Mar', 'Mie', 'Jue', 'Vie', 'Sab', 'Dom'],
            onSelect: function(value, date) { 
                $("#my_calendar > div > div.ui-datepicker-group").slice(-3).remove();   
                //$('#my_calendar').multiDatesPicker("refresh");
            }
        });

        $("#my_calendar > div > div.ui-datepicker-group").slice(-3).remove();               
   });
```

When multidatespicker load, show 13 months correctly. But, when event onselect fires, then refresh multidatespicker and show 16 months. I've tried to put ".slice(-3).remove()" also into onSelect body, but it has not worked.

How can I avoid the refresh?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

I've modified "jquery-ui.js" library on this way:
1. Adding a new property called numberOfHiddenMonths:

```
/* Determine the number of hidden months to show. */
_getNumberOfHiddenMonths: function (inst) {
    var numHiddenMonths = this._get(inst, "numberOfHiddenMonths");
    return (numHiddenMonths == null ? 0 : numHiddenMonths);
}
```

2. Updating "_updateDatepicker" function adding these lines:

   ```
   _updateDatepicker: function(inst) {
   this.maxRows = 4; //Reset the max number of rows being displayed (see #7043)
   datepicker_instActive = inst; // for delegate hover events
   inst.dpDiv.empty().append(this._generateHTML(inst));
   this._attachHandlers(inst);

   /* This is the code necesary to hide the months */    
   var numOfHiddenMonths=this._getNumberOfHiddenMonths(inst);
   if (numOfHiddenMonths>0) $("#" + inst.id + " > div > div.ui-datepicker-group").slice(-1*numOfHiddenMonths).remove();
   /*------------- End -------------------------------------*/
   ```

Now, I can use the next code to hide the number of months that I want, in my case, 3 months:

```
 $('#calendario').multiDatesPicker({
            numberOfMonths: [4, 4],
            numberOfHiddenMonths: 3,
            defaultDate: '01-01-2015',
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            monthNames: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
            dayNamesMin: ['Lun', 'Mar', 'Mie', 'Jue', 'Vie', 'Sab', 'Dom']
        });
```